get ig user from user id using instagram basic display api
I'm developing Instagram user tracking.
So, the user initially log in in via Instagram oauth with the URL below.
(https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=****&redirect_uri=****&response_type=code&scope=user_profile)
After that, I store the user ID on db through getting by the address https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token.
After, I want to retrieve the Instagram user's username and avatar url via the user ID.
How should I implement this?
I tried using the HTTP request below to implement this.
GET https://graph.instagram.com/{api-version}/{user-id}
  ?fields={fields}
  &access_token={access-token}

However, to put the access token in the access_token, I only have the user-id in the db.
Is it possible to get it through the Instagram app's client_secret?
+) I've looked into long lived tokens, but then the server has to keep refreshing the token before it expires.

"I've looked into long lived tokens, but then the server has to keep refreshing the token before it expires." - and ...? Is anything stopping you from implementing that?

To implement this, I need to store the user's access token in my db. However, I think this would be a security issue, and I would also need to renew it every 60 days, which would be a lot of work if I had a lot of users.
So I'm wondering if I can get the user info with app's secret key
